# Soft keyboard auto show when use AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I don't know why when I use `AsyncTask` to load data to an Adapter, after `AsyncTask` finishes, the soft keyboard shows on screen.

There is a `Edittext` in the activity. If I delete the `EditText` on the Activity, after the `AsyncTask` finishes, the soft keyboard does not show.

I use this code on `onPostExecute()` but it does not work:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        hideSoftKeyboard(SearchActivity.this);
        RecommendAdapter mAdap = new RecommendAdapter(con, mLocation);
        mListview.setAdapter(mAdap);

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {

            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: what is `hideSoftKeyboard()`? please show the definition of `hideSoftKeyboard()` too..

Comment: try `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);`

Comment: It's not work, I think the soft keyboard is open after the Asyctask finish so If use hideSoftKeyboard() in onPostExecute( ) ,so the function was not called.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know the answer.It because I use   so it always focus on   .Add the `android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the Layout so the soft keyboard not show.